# error al mostrar datos php mvc PDO

Tags: php, mvc, pdo

**Hola tengo un error al mostrador los datos de una consulta en la vista, ya estuve buscando información y nada me funciona quizás sea un detalle en mi lógica pero me gustaría una segunda opinión **

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Modelo

```
<?php
include("Config/database.php");
class LoginModel
{
    public function Validar($user,$pdw)
    {
        $Conn = new Conexion();
        $link = $Conn->Conectar();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE Nom_Usuario = ? AND Contraseña = ?";
        $stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $user); 
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $pdw);
        $stmt->execute();
        $Result = $stmt->rowCount();

        if ($Result > 0) {
            $Result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $id = $Result['IdClave'];
            $sql2 = "SELECT P.Nombre,P.Apellido_Paterno,P.Apellido_Materno, U.Nom_Usuario,U.`Contraseña`
            FROM persona AS P, usuarios AS U, empleado AS E
            WHERE E.IdPersona = P.IdPersona AND E.idClave = U.IdClave AND E.idClave = ?";
            $stmt2 = $link->prepare($sql2);
            $stmt2->bindParam(1, $id);
            $stmt2->execute();           
            $datos = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if(!empty($datos)) {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['Nom_User'] = $datos['Nom_Usuario'];
                $_SESSION['Nombre_Persona'] = $datos['Nombre'];
                $_SESSION['Paterno'] = $datos['Apellido_Paterno'];
                $_SESSION['Materno'] = $datos['Apellido_Materno'];
                $_SESSION['Password'] = $datos['Contraseña'];
            }
        }
        return $datos;
             
    }
}
```

Controller

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

desde aqui lo mando a llamar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui lo quiero mostrar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour].Por favor no publiques código o mensajes de error/trazas de pila en imágenes, publica directamente el texto del código, el texto de los errores y los _stack traces_. Esto hace que sea menos complicado, para quien quiera ayudarte, investigar sobre el tema y hacer sus propias pruebas/adaptaciones al código, al escribir una respuesta y de esa forma aumenta tus posibilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola. Por favor, pon tanto el código como los mensajes de error en forma de texto. Las capturas de imagen impiden analizar el problema y suponen más pérdida de tiempo para ti. Pulsa en [edit] y haz copia / pega del código y del error. Es más simple para todos.

Comment: no puedo poner todo el codigo me marca Tu publicación parece contener código que no tiene el formato apropiado para código. Aplica una sangría de cuatro espacios a todo el código mediante el botón de código de la barra de herramientas o el método abreviado del teclado CTRL+K. Para obtener más ayuda de edición, haz clic en el ícono [?] de la barra de herramientas. y no hace nada al precionar contrl-k

Comment: Selecciona todo el bloque de código, luego pulsa en el icono **`{ }`**  de la barra de edición para indentar los trozos de código.

Comment: Aparte de las recomendaciones que te dan en los comenatrios anteriores, veo un poco ilógica la manera en que quieres acceder a los datos. Si en el modelo estás asignando valores a variables de sesión `$_SESSION['Nom_User'] = $datos['Nom_Usuario'];`, lo lógico es que tomes esos datos de la variable de sesión que ya tiene el valor asignado `$_SESSION['Nom_User']; `. No me queda claro qué datos necesitas que se recorran en el `array` **$datos** que, de hecho, no existe en **test.php** ya que no hay una llamada a la función.

Comment: Bueno la verdad es que soy realmente un principiante en esto de la programación y derivado de lo que estuve leyendo según yo al llamar la función del modelo en este caso  ``$ObjModel = new LoginModel();``       ``$ObjModel->Validar($user,$pdw);`` deberia tener disponible para usar la variable ``$datos`` que es quien esta guardando los datos de la consulta previa, los cuale si estan ya que si imprimo in ``print_r($datos);`` me arroja el array con la informacion que necesito mostrar en la vista

Comment: ¿En qué parte del código exactamente si pones un `print_r($datos);` dices que te muestra los datos? El mensaje de error es muy claro, dice que no está encontrando ninguna variable llamada `$datos`. Explica por favor cómo haces para tener a `$datos` en contexto.